# Which package to install based only on import line

Tags: python

I am very new to Python, and I am attempting to reproduce an [example](https://www.quantstart.com/articles/Forex-Trading-Diary-1-Automated-Forex-Trading-with-the-OANDA-API) (not necessary to answer the question). If all I have is `import threading` from within the code I assumed I could just run `pip install threading` however the module is not found. When I searched for a different package name in the Python package manager I came across hundreds. Why doesn't the pip command work, and how do I know which package to install?

**My exact error**

```
:\Users\king\Desktop\_REPOS\misc\stock_analysis\forex\python\pythonv2>python trading.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trading.py", line 1, in <module>
    import Queue #pip install queuelib
ImportError: No module named 'Queue'
```

**Version info**

Python 3.5 32bit (64 bit OS)

Comment: `threading` is part of the standard library; it should already be part of your base Python installation. In general, there isn't necessarily any relation between the name of a module and the package which provides it.

Comment: Can you post your exact error here?

Comment: [`Queue`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) is the name of the module in Python 2. You are using Python 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first hit on google (search: python threading) actually gave me:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html (the URL itself already indicate it)

This means it's a library module so it should be already available to you without extra installs.

In case your Python is limited in a way and doesn't have it by default, please update your question with your Python version and way it was installed.

For future reference, you were mostly doing the right thing, a lot of modules have the same name as their import statements, but otherwise, in almost all case, a simple Google search will suffice.

Comment: And you can check that Python is pretty much "batteries included" for most things. https://docs.python.org/2/library/

Comment: I just updated my post with more details, hope they help. I am happy to provide more info if needed but as I mentioned I am very new to Python, so please give specific commands if anything else would be useful

Comment: hmm, the error doesn't mention threading and also, it seems the error has given you the solution right there `pip install queuelib`, did you try?

Comment: ah, I just googled again (search: python Queue) and found:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html

which mentions `The Queue module has been renamed to queue in Python 3.` So in this case, just update the code to use lowercase `queue` (everywhere `Queue` is mentioned). Also, I know you're new to Python, but you did try Google first, right?

Comment: Haha, I did try google, but my basic assumption that it was a library error was incorrect.... you know what they say about those who assume :(

Comment: very true, and the differences between Python 2 and 3 are quite annoying, especially for new users. anyway, the docs in the Python ecosystem are generally of very high quality, enjoy it! :) and good luck.